# Syntax Error in _maps.scss in Susy 2.0

Tags: susy-compass, susy-sass

```
"Syntax error: Invalid CSS after \"...th($_keys, $_n)\": expected \")\", was \": $_value);\"
on line 57 of *myPath*/sass/lib/susy/math/_maps.scss 
from line 4 of *myPath*/sass/lib/susy/_math.scss
from line 4 of *myPath*/sass/lib/susy/language/_susy.scss 
from line 4 of *myPath*/sass/lib/_susy.scss 
from line 4 of *myPath*/sass/screen.scss"
```

I am getting this syntax error when trying to use the new Susy 2 with Compass. I wanted to upgrade from version 1 manually and copied the contents of the downloaded *sass* folder into my *sass/lib*. Therefore, I do the import with `@import "lib/_susy";`.

Anyone knows if this is my fault or a bug?

Comment: Bugs should probably be filed on [GitHub](https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues) rather than Stack Overflow. I've never seen this error before, and the syntax on that line looks correct to me. What version of Sass are you using?

Comment: I was using Sass 3.3.0.alpha.2 (Bleeding Edge) but since the new Susy requires unpublished versions of Sass and Compass (which I wasn't aware of - maybe make it more obvious on your site?) I decided to stick to Susy One until it's been rolled out officially.

Comment: Our only requirement is Sass `3.3.0.rc.1` or higher, which is available and published as a gem. If you were already using a pre-release alpha, I'm not sure I see the harm in upgrading to a much more stable release candidate.

Comment: I installed Sass 3.3 only because I was testing with Susy 2. I will try again when both Sass and Susy are finally rolled out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had these problems as well. To fix, I had to:

1. Upgrade to Sass 3.3 RC5 (`gem install sass -v 3.3.0.rc.5`)
2. Upgrade to Compass 1.0.0.alpha.18 (`gem install compass -v 1.0.0.alpha.18`)

This should fix it for you, too.

Edit: Sass 3.3 has now officially been released, so you can install the production version. Compass 1 is still in prerelease.

Comment: Sorry, it is not possible for me right now to check if this works. As commented above, I will stick to Susy One for now. I hope this will help somebody else. Thanks!